# Adding items to object in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, element, addition

I have an object like this, and I want to simply add items to it using pure JavaScript. Because the following object is not an array and it has name defined.

Such as "John" and further age and feedback. How can I add similar object to it in Javascript?

```js
var emps = {
  "John": {
    "age": "30",
    "feedback": "There is a reason behind this"

  },
  "Amy": {
    "age": "22",
    "userComment": "No reasons"

  }
};
```

I want to add Rob now to it keeping the structure same but through JavaScript code.

```
"Rob": {
  "age": "42",
  "userComment": "No reasons"
}
emps.push() //Something to it. I am confused with it the "Name" being id.
```

It should become:

```js
var emps = {
  "John": {
    "age": "30",
    "feedback": "There is a reason behind this"

  },
  "Amy": {
    "age": "22",
    "userComment": "No reasons"

  },
  "Rob": {
    "age": "42",
    "userComment": "No reasons"

  }
};
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a _JSON Object_. JSON is _always_ a string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please learn [the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation).

Comment: `emps.Jane = { age: "50", comment: "" }`. What is the issue here? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the exact result that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Push is for Arrays. You want `emps["Rob"] =  {
  "age": "42",
  "userComment": "No reasons"
}`

Comment: Thanks it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
emps["Alice"] ={"age":30,"feedback":"Hello"};
```

Take on consideration your exposed code has bad construction.

emps.push() should work if you do a well formed array.